# Are they really called "linear panels"?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating a Russian description of a building project, and the house in the project is partially covered with "linear panels". It turns out there's a whole large Russian article in Wikipedia about these panels - [Линеарная панель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

However, there are no articles in other Wikipedias. I'm not sure that the term **linear panel** is a common one used in English for this type of panel, so I decided to ask here. Is it? If not, what do I call these panels?

Although the Multitran Dictionary provides the translation *[linear panel](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&langlist=2)* in English, I'm not sure, because the translation is user-submitted.

Here's one example with green "linear panels" covering a wall:

[image]

Comment: Linear means arranged in a straight line. It does not refer to the composition of the material

Comment: Yes, but in our case this classing is indeed composed in long straight strips, that's why they are called "linear" in Russian )) @Kris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it siding, and if they are made of plastic, then I would say vinyl siding. Other materials would include wood and fiber-board.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you show I would go with "Green plastic cladding" or "plastic cladding" shown in green, with other colors available if relevant.

Common terms I have seen are :

1. Decorative panels
2. Facing panels
3. Building Facades
4. Cladding

There are some types of cladding known by the manufacturer's name or trademark as well.

The material can range from plastic, wood, concrete and even concrete to look like brick or stone...